# How to generate a key for php file that expires in 10 days. And other users can't execute the api after key expiration

Tags: php, authentication, access-token

I want to generate a key which is valid for 10 days from the day it is generated. So that anyone having the key can run the api for 10 days. I want this to be purely in php and no session or cookie should be used.

I have tried storing the key and date in file seperated by tab. But I want something that it does not require file also for storage. All this can be done with using php only.

I want that any one with the key can pass it as URI parameter such as 
http:www.example.com/key=abcdqwerty and this key should be valid for 10 days only.

Comment: I just want to use php that is either store it in array or something similar to that. I have done it using database and files too.

Comment: It is not storing data it is maintaining the generated token for 10 days.

Comment: is there something wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 2):

A cheap way is to md5 the date and use that as the key.
Then to validate loop the past 10 days and make them md5 and see if they match.

This means you don't need to save the keys and will be safe for most users.
Only the most nerdy nerds will try and figure out what the key is and if it can be broken.

```
// Create key
$key = md5("2019-05-16");
//$key = "5b6ed05ac59c0cae26957e39aceaa204";

//Validate
for($i=0; $i <= 10; $i++){
    if($key == md5(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-" . $i . " days")))){
        echo "valid";
    }
}
```

Working code with one being valid the other not, see output with one valid string only.
https://3v4l.org/Is4oT

Comment: this is the perfect answer im needed